# Add cell values to a list, filling cells without empty cells difficult to explain. (see picture in description)

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where I want end users to be able to check of the items they need. the checked off items then need to be added to a list beside the items. the problem im having is that i can't figure out how to get excel to add info to the lines without skipping lines where items aren't checked. this is difficult to explain, but the picture attached show exactly what i mean. At the end of the list there should be a sum of the prices and this sum should always be shown after the last line with data so it should be able to move depending on how many lines of data there is. so this is my problem.

```
Sub MakeList()
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 4) = True Then
            Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i, 2)
            Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 4) = True Then
            Sum = Sum + Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i

    Cells(24, 4) = Sum

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to simply add an offset value every time a cell is not included. This would just be a simple counter in the `Else` portion of the `If` statement.

```
Sub MakeList()

Dim i As Long

Dim Sum As Double
Sum = 0

Dim n As Long
n = 0

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 4) = True Then
        Cells(1 + i - n, 6) = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(1 + i - n, 7) = Cells(i, 2)
        Cells(1 + i - n, 8) = Cells(i, 3)

        Sum = Sum + Cells(i, 3)
    Else
        n = n + 1
    End If

Next i

    'Place sum at the bottom of the original table
    'Cells(24, 4) = Sum

    'Place sum at the bottom of the output table
    Cells(i + 1 - n, 8) = Sum

End Sub
```

This tells your code that every time an item is not included, the output should be offset by that row. I also moved the summation inside the original loop, to avoid looping twice. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you!
i still need to add the sum to the end of the list though?

Comment: Copy that, just saw that sentence of the question. See edited answer. It utilizes the fact that the values for both `n` and `i` are still stored.

Comment: A small change and it works! thank you!
 cells(i+1-n+1,8) or else it will fill it into the last line.